# Google Analytics Advanced filter to Combine / merge multiple instances of URL? Find & Replace UTM parameters

Tags: regex

I'm looking to use Advanced Filter Search and Replace on GA to combine all url instances of my blog page (multiple UTM parameters)

so Urls like the following:

/blogs/in-the-garden/diy-garden-bar-ideas-for-summer?mc_cid=etc.....
/blogs/in-the-garden/diy-garden-bar-ideas-for-summer?fbclid=etc.....

I want to filter as:
/blogs/in-the-garden/diy-garden-bar-ideas-for-summer

This is the plan for my filter:

Request URI
Field A: ^(/blogs/in-the-garden/diy-garden-bar-ideas-for-summer)(?).*

Request URI
Output To: $A1

Is this written correctly? I'm new to Reg Ex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exclude that parameter from the **View settings**, you don't need a filter:

[image]

However, as XTOTHEL says, the change will work from the day of saving onwards, not for historical data.

Note: fbclid is not an UTM parameter. It comes from Facebook posts link.

Real UTM parameters (utm_source, utm_medium, ...) are automatically removed from Google Analytics

Comment: thanks this looks like what I need, I think the confusion came from me searching how to remove utm parameters :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Data that's captured in GA already WON'T BE AFFECTED by the filters. They're not retroactive.
2. If you want to remove fbclid then use the query string parameter exclusion feature: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1010249?hl=en